# Sort, compare and display from Struct in C

Tags: c, comparison

I need to ask user to insert Number of Processes, Process ID and Waiting time
then i have to sort, compare and print based on Process priority
I am new on C, I can't figure out how to do it
Any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance*/

```
struct Process {
  int Id;
  int Prio;
  int Time;
};

struct Process process[100];


void init() {
  printf("Enter number of processes:\n ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  while(n<3) {
    printf("Number has to be grater than 2\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
  }

  for (int x=0; x<n; x++) {
    printf("Process %d ID:\n ", x+1);
    scanf("%d",&process[x].Id);
    printf("Process %d priority:\n ", x+1);
    scanf("%d",&process[x].Prio);
    printf("Process %d time:\n ", x+1);
    scanf("%d",&process[x].Time);
    }
}

void priority() {
  for (int x=0; x<n; x++) {
    printf("%d",process[x].Id);
    printf("        %d",process[x].Prio);
    printf("           %d\n\n",process[x].Time);
  }
}

void line(int dashes) {
  for(int x=1;x<dashes;x++) {
    printf("-");
  }
}

void display() {
  printf("\n");
  printf("                        PROCESS SCHEDULING\n");
  line(90);
  printf("\n");
  printf("ID");
  printf("    PRIORITY");
  printf("    WAITING TIME");
  line(90);
  printf("\n\n");
}
int main() {
  init();
  display();
  priority();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question, you need to sort processes based on priority, simply apply any sort algorithm and compare by process.priority. What's your trouble exactly? Sintax?

Comment: is this an assignment? which tutorial are you following? have you tried to compile this code (where is the variable "n")? which compiler? which operating system is this on?

Comment: this is a assignment IssamTP. The think is I don't know the algorithm/sintax to apply.

Comment: I have defined the variable "n" on top of my code. The code is working, but only printing the data as entered.

Comment: Well, then you'll find my answer down below. Insert the call between init and display. lemme know. Please accept it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

For sorting you can apply any sorting algorithm (bubble sort, insertion sort, heap sort .. ) but when comparing adjacent elements, compare their priorities. Something like

```
if(process[index1].Prio < process[index2].Prio)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of BubbleSort, an elementary algorithm for sorting. This is not the best around you can find, but it's one of the easiest to understand. Reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

```
void SortProcesses()
{
  int right_bound = n - 1; /* Assuming you've declared n as number of processes inputed. */
  Process swap;

  while( right_bound > 0 )
  {
    for( int i = 0; i < right_bound; i++ )
    {
       if( process[i].Prio > process[i + 1].Prio )
       {
         swap.Id = process[i+1].Id;
         swap.Prio = process[i+1].Prio;
         swap.Time = process[i+1].Time;
         process[i+1].Id = process[i].Id;
         // ... idem for Prio and Time;
         process[i].Id = swap.Id;
         // ... idem for Prio and Time
         right_bound--;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much you all. I've used another for loop instead of While loop.

Comment: There are more way to do same thing.